# How to show @PostMapping parameters in swagger-ui generated docs?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui` for autogenerated `REST` documentation.

Problem: any `GET` requests are documented just fine. But when it comes to `POST` requests, the request body parameter descriptions are not shown in the swagger ui. But why?

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    @GetMapping
    public PersonRsp findPerson(PersonDTO p) {
        //this works just fine an shows the @ApiParam fields in documentation
    } 

    @PostMapping
    public PersonRsp updatePerson(@RequestBody PersonDTO p) {
        //service logic
        return rsp;
    }
}

class PersonDTO {
    @ApiParam(required = true, value = "the persons family name")
    private String lastname;

    private String firstname;

    @ApiParam(value = "date of birth in format YYYY-MM-DD")
    private Date dob;
}
```

Question: how can I get the `@ApiParam` annotation hints being show in the swagger-ui documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: it seems one has to use `@ApiModelProperty("some description")` for `POST` requests, and `@ApiParam` for `GET` requests.